# Agregar un Value/Name a un link que manda un submit

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo un problema en entender como funciona el método submit.onchange para poder actualizar un campo en mi base de datos con `Laravel`

Primero tengo un menu desplegable links a rutas:

```
<!--------  Ejemplo  ---------->
<li class="">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="">Ejemplo
    <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu pull-right">
    <li><a href="{{url('/Opcion1')}}">Opcion1</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{url('/Opcion2')}}">Opcion2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<!--------  /Ejemplo  ---------->
```

Aquí muestro una colección en las opciones, proveniente de una base de datos:

```
    <li><a href="{{url('/Opcion1')}}">Opcion1</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{url('/Opcion2')}}">Opcion2</a></li>
```

cambio a mostrar la lista de cuentas :

```
@if($Cuentas->count())  
@foreach($Cuentas as $CuentasOpciones)

<li>
<a href="{{CuentasOpciones->id}}">{{CuentasOpciones->nombre}}</a>
</li>

@endforeach
@endif
```

Aqui me trato de apoyar en la logica del mismo menu de Laravel para mandar el submit.onclick dentro de las etiquetas `<li></li>` Se que aqui tengo mi error ya que no estoy entregando un nombre y value al link que mando en el submit pero no estoy seguro de como integrarlo:

```
<a class="dropdown-item"
   href="{{ route('CuentasUpdate') }}" <-- no estoy seguro si este bien repetir la ruta
   onclick="event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('CuentasUpdateForm').submit();">
                            {{$CuentasHeaderList->nombre}}
</a>
<form id="CuentasUpdateForm" 
      action="{{route('CuentasUpdate', Auth::user()->id)}}" <-- trato de hacer update a un valor del usuario logeado
      method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf
</form>
```

Me dirijo a mi documento de rutas `web.php` :

```
Route::PATCH('/CuentasUpdate/Auth::user()->id', 
'HomeController@CuentasUpdate')->name('CuentasUpdate');
```

Al no mandar mi value para 'ultima_cuenta' me muestra el siguiente error:
Too few arguments to function :

```
App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::CuentasUpdate(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected
```

Mi controlador se ve asi:

```
public function CuentasUpdate(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'ultima_cuenta' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
    Users::where('id',$id)->update($validatedData);
    return redirect('home');
}
```

veo que el error esta en que no estoy pasando el valor y nombre el link a mi controlador pero no estoy seguro coo implementar esta parte

Comment: cambia tu ruta a `Route::PATCH('/CuentasUpdate/{id}, ...'. Pues ese dato ya se lo estas dando en el action del form. Poniendo entre llave la id, laravel lo tomará como un parámetro, seguramente el que te dice que está faltando

Comment: gracias pero sigo sin encontrar como mandar el nombre y valor "ultima_cuenta" para que haga el update :,( es horrible ser nuevo en esto

Comment: tendrías que agregar esos valores al <form> en inputs antes de enviar el form. Pero no sé de donde salen... ¿ es alguna de las variables como `$CuentasHeaderList->nombre`?

Comment: si, en realidad tengo en usuarios ultima_Cuenta y quiero hacer update al campo del usuario con el valor dentro de ´$CuentasHeaderList->nombre´

Comment: no entendí bien de donde obtienes los valores que quieres enviar. Para agregar los inputs sería algo así: `$('#CuentasUpdateForm').append('<input type="hidden" name="ultima_cuenta" value="{{ $ultima_Cuenta }}" />');` antes de `('CuentasUpdateForm').submit()`

Comment: perdon e estado tratando, pero no e entendido, basicamente que meta el input dentro del link asi?: <a class="dropdown-item" 
   href="{{ route('CuentasUpdate', Auth::user()->id) }}" 
   onclick="event.preventDefault();

$('#CuentasUpdateForm').append('<input type="hidden" name="ultima_cuenta" value="{{ $ultima_Cuenta }}" />');


   document.getElementById('CuentasUpdateForm').submit();">
                            {{$CuentasOpciones->nombre}}     
</a>

Comment: Algo así, pero no creo que te funcione poniendo toda la función en el atributo onclick, pues tiene comillas dobles. Además, si vas a usar la misma función para varios links, sería mejor que la escribas dentro de una etiqueta <script> y le pases el valor como parámetro. En un momento te escribo una respuesta de ejemplo para cómo lo puedes hacer, pues es muy largo para ponerlo en comentarios

Comment: gracias me seria muy ultil para validar la respuesta cuando se solucione, actual mente coloque un input hiden con el nombre y el value dentro del FORM que estan actualizando pero no se por que esta colocando el primer valor de la tabla y no el que selecione

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar algo así:
En el link no hace falta un valor para el atributo `href`, pues no lo vas a usar.
En el atributo `onclick`, pones `preventDefault()` para que al clickear el link no te redirija al donde `href` dice que va el enlace.
Luego llamas a la función `updateItem()` pasándole como parámetro el valor que quieres insertar en el `<form>`.

```
<a class="dropdown-item update-link" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); updateItem('{{ $CuentasHeaderList->nombre }}')">
   {{ $CuentasHeaderList->nombre }}
</a>
```

Dentro de la etiqueta `<script>` creas la función `updateItem()` que recibe como parámetro el valor que le pasaste desde el link.
Asignas el formulario a una variable solo por comodidad, pues lo vas a usar dos veces.
Agregas un input al formulario con el valor que recibiste desde el link.
Luego envías el formulario.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updateItem(value) {
        var form = $('#CuentasUpdateForm');
        form.append('<input name="ultima_cuenta" value="' + value + '" />');
        form.submit();
    };
})
</script>
```

En el atributo `action` del formulario, le pasas la ruta por el nombre y la id del usuario logueado como parámetro.
Agregas el método `patch` y el `token` como inputs

```
<form id="CuentasUpdateForm" action="{{ route('CuentasUpdate', Auth::user()->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf
</form>
```

En la ruta recibes la id como parámetro, ponieńdola entre llaves y se lo pasas al controlador:

```
Route::PATCH('/CuentasUpdate/{id}', 'HomeController@CuentasUpdate')->name('CuentasUpdate');
```

Finalmente, en el controlador, validas el campo en el request y actualizas la Base de Datos.

Comment: Acuérdate de explicar tu código, para que la solución nos sea entendible a todos